# I can't make Highcharts phantomJs export server work

Tags: highcharts, export, phantomjs

Big thanks in advance.

I want to set up a phantomjs Highcharts export server. It should accept json options as input and output jpeg image files.

Here is what I do:

1. I download server side js code from this repo: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs
2. I download phantomjs 1.6.0
3. run

   ```
   phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3001
   ```

Then I tried to use client code in this site: http://export.highcharts.com/demo to send request. I changed the form action url from this:

```
    <form id="exportForm" action="./" method="POST">
```

to this:

```
    <form id="exportForm" action="http://0.0.0.0:3001" method="POST">
```

and clicked 'Highcharts config object (JSON)'. All I get is this message:

> Failed rendering: 
>   SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

Since the same request can be processed correctly in Highcharts server, the error must be in the Highcharts server side js code I'm using. I also tried following command:

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.js \
                                -outfile chart.png -scale 2.5 -width 300
```

With this code in `options.js`:

```
{
  infile: {
            xAxis: {
                        categories:['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
                                    'May','Jun','Jul','Aug',
                                    'Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                },
            series:[
                {
                    data:[29.9,71.5,106.4,129.2,
                          144.0,176.0,135.6,148.5,
                          216.4,194.1,95.6,54.4]
                }]
          },
          callback: function(chart){
          chart.renderer
               .arc(200,150,100,50,-Math.PI,0)
               .attr({fill:'#FCFFC5',stroke:'black','stroke-width':1})
               .add();
          },
 constr: "Chart",
 outfile: "//tmp//chart.png"
}
```

And it generates the png successfully.

I guess Highchart didn't put much work in the exporting functions and I found some typo in the highcharts-convert.js file. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I guess there is mis-understanding in the so called "JSON" string. The Javascript export server **does not accept any real "JSON" string**. A real "JSON" string would have all strings quoted, some thing like

```
 {
       "value": [1,2,3],
       "name": "jack"
 }
```

What the export server accepts are actually a **piece of Javascript code to create a Javascript object**, like:

```
 {
       value: [1,2,3],
       name: "jack"
 }
```

This is because the server will use this string as part of the Javascript code in the generated webpage. I wrote a small function to convert JSON string into this format and pass it to the server, it finally works.

```
var getUnQuotedJsonString = function (str) {
  return str.replace(/"\w+":/g, function(s, key) {
    return s.replace(/"/g, "");
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi tuo, I tried this format `{infile:"{xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]};",callback:"function(chart) {}",constr:"Chart",outfile:"//tmp//chart.png"}` but still not working. Could you give me a working example?

Comment: Don, your string is neither a valid JSON string or "Javascript code to create object". Here is a working string: 

{infile:{xAxis:{categories:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]},series:[{data:[29.9,71.5,106.4,129.2,144,176,135.6,148.5,216.4,194.1,95.6,54.4]}]},constr:"Chart",outfile:"//tmp//chart.png"}

You can try to create an object in JS and use JSON.stringify to get the correct JSON string. Then you can use the function I provided before to convert it into the format that Highcharts export server accepts.

Comment: I just tried both these strings and neither seem to work any more. The demo page (export.highcharts.com/demo) seems to be using a completely different POST syntax, but that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the string in the demo page, the strings in both of the comments above and I'm getting a 500 error, with the response `Failed rendering:`
I'm using Fiddler to test and my post header is:  
User-Agent: Fiddler  
Host: 127.0.0.1:3003  
Content-Length: 227  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error when I tried to send in a JSON string that was longer than what my server hosting the highcharts exporter WAR file would accept. Check your message length parameter in your server. Make sure it is long enough to hold the request sent. Now, since you do not mention what export server you are using (java or PHP) I would imagine you did not actually set up the web front end for the export server and you just have the headless command line export set up (phantomJS + some highcharts js files). To use the exporting server for use in the front end (like when a user clicks on the export buttons on the web page) you also need to set up [Java](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java) or [PHP](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/php).

Comment: Thanks wergeld. The new PhantomJs server don't require Java or PHP. It's relatively new. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs). I don't know how it works but it sure can work without Java or Batik.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the Phantoms HTTP server which is started by

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host ... -port ...
```

expects the parameters send in JSON format. Please read, the [documentation](http://docs.highcharts.com/#render-charts-on-the-server), parapgraph *'start as a webserver'*

Out of curiosity... what typo did you found?

Comment: there is a "length" mis-spelled to "lenght", that's all I can remember now.

Comment: thanks, this is fixed now. [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/f81b7f8207a3575209cc46ca4f7d5ce43791a73f)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a similar function to solve this for PHP if anyone is looking to remove the quotes from the result of `json_encode` -

```
function unQuote($str){
return preg_replace_callback('/"\w+":/',
                        function ($match){
                             return str_replace('"', '', $match[0]);
                         }, 
                         $str );
}
```