# Highcharts phantomjs export server can't parse json string

Tags: json, curl, highcharts

I can't get the highcharts export server to work when running phantomjs as a server.

I am able to get the Highcharts export server working when I use the first method they suggest:

> phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js

But when I try to use phantomjs as a server I always get:

> Failed rendering: 
>   SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

I have tried using the sample string Highcharts provided and the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467331/i-cant-make-highcharts-phantomjs-export-server-work/17716360#17716360)

my post request looks like this:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{infile:{xAxis:{categories:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep‌​","Oct","Nov","Dec"]},series:[{data:[29.9,71.5,106.4,129.2,144,176,135.6,148.5,21‌​6.4,194.1,95.6,54.4]}]},constr:"Chart",outfile:"//tmp//chart.png"}' localhost:3003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes. This works for me.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' 127.0.0.1:3005
```

*Note: The 'outfile' parameter has no use here. Running phantomjs as a server, outputs always a image as a 64bit string representation.*

Comment: Still can't get it to work, now I am getting: ERROR: the options variable was not available, contains the infile an syntax error? see{xAxis: {categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}

Comment: Actually, I got the latest version of all the highcharts files, and now this works.

Comment: Gert, I've scoured the net and can't find anything on dynamically changing the x axis type in highcharts. Would you mind taking a look at my question here -> [Changing X axis type from category to datetime on drilldown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234418/changing-x-axis-type-from-category-to-datetime-on-drilldown) Apologies for hijacking post, but I'm sure an answer to this question will be valuable to other people as well! Thanks!